# Taking an autosys job Off Hold but not wanting it to run immediately

Tags: autosys

I have 2 jobs in autosys: Job 1 and Job 2. Job2 will only run if Job1 is a success.

Now, in a normal scenario, Job1 and Job2 will run in succession as part of a daily batch.

But, sometimes,  I need to re run Job1 without kicking off Job2. But if I just re run Job1, its success will automatically kick off Job 2.
So, I put Job2 'On Hold' and run Job1. All good so far.

Now, it is my experience that when I put Job 2 'Off Hold', it will immediately start running. I don't want that.
http://autosys-tutorials.blogspot.ca/2011/04/autosys-quick-reference.html

What I want is for Job2 to go into a Runnable state so that it gets picked up in the next batch run.
What status should I set Job2 to?

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure whether you got answer for your doubt, there is one more option to do not let the ON_HOLD job to run immediately when off_hold it.

1. change the job 2 status from ON_HOLD to INACTIVE, so job 2 will not start immediately and same time job 2 will start running once condition(job 1 went to success state) met when job is in INACTIVE state.
2. If you mark the job 2 to ONICE, it will allow the dependent job to start if it has.

Regards,
Kaliraja (HP Autosys Team)

Answer (score 2):

In this situation you should put Job2 'On Ice' before re-running Job1, instead of putting it 'On Hold'. From the [link](http://autosys-tutorials.blogspot.ca/2011/04/autosys-quick-reference.html) you posted:

> The difference between "on hold" and "on ice" is that when an "on
>   hold" job is taken off hold, if its starting conditions are already
>   satisfied, it will be scheduled to run, and it will run. On the other
>   hand, if an "on ice" job is taken "off ice," it will not start, even
>   if its starting conditions are already satisfied. This job will not
>   run until its starting conditions reoccur.

Comment: If I put on Ice, Job3,Job4...Job10 will run (I omitted these in my example for simplicity). I don;t want job3...job10 to run. I only want job1 to run as standalone.

Comment: In that case, maybe you should look into separating the jobs out into different boxes with start_time constraints. That way, if Job1 was in its own box, and all boxes dependent on it had start_time constraints, they wouldn't run immediately after Job1 finished but would only enter a running state when their start_time constraints were met.

Answer (score 1):

You can put job2 on hold and run job1. After the completion of JOb1, change the status of Job2 to success,so that it can start next time as per schedule and based on its conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Put Job_2 as 'On_Ice' before starting Job_1

Answer (score 0):

You can place job 2 ON HOLD, But mark the job as success/Failure (ensure Job2 has no other dependency on this state)

Answer (score 0):

You can put job2 on hold and run job1. After the completion of JOb1, change the status of Job2 to INACTIVE so that it can start next time as per schedule.

Answer (score 0):

You could use override_job subcommand to bypass the execution only one time. The next schedule will automatically pick up the job to run.

This example shows how to define a one-time job override. The following script runs the job RunData with no conditions (where some had been previously specified) and outputs the results to a different output file:
UNIX:
override_job: RunData
condition: NULL
std_out_file: "tmp\SpecialRun.out"

If you want to cancel a override job defined, then use the below -

override_job: RunData delete

Answer (score 0):

Options for the scenario:
1- Place job2 on "No Execution" each time you want to run ONLY job1, later remove it.
2- Place look-back as success condition as s(job1,0) on job2 for permanent fix to meet your adhoc request & permanent scheduled run if you are placing it on-hold & later removing it.
3- Place it on-Ice, but make sure there is no dependent job for Job2.

Answer (score 0):

About your concern that you don't want to put Job2 'ON_ICE' because this will run the remaining jobs (job3 - job10), I think this scenario will not happen unless your main box is running. Since you've mentioned that you are going to run the job1 as standalone, the main box should not be running since, if so, job1 will be automatically triggered. Having said this, make sure that the main box is not running when you want to run the job1 alone. Else, the thing that your are saying will happen.

Answer (score -1):

Put these jobs in the same box, put job 2 ON_HOLD, FORCESTART the box, wait for job 1 to finish with SUCCESS, KILLJOB the box, take job 2 OFF_HOLD, change status of all jobs in box to SUCCESS.